# Using different git repos in OSGI application

Tags: git, osgi

i am new to git, and i have an OSGI application
and i want to make different git repos, and each repo consists of some OSGI bundles 
and all the bundles/repos will be related to the master repo too.
please give me some guide about how this process should go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what branches are made for. If you just can't have all bundles in the same repository, split them and put them in different repositories.

Comment: i want to split bundles to different branches to apply permissions.

Comment: One more reason to use multiple repositories.

Comment: after some reading you are right, please give me some guide on how to do that.

Comment: That depends, how many developers will work on that repositories. You can use Gitolite, but that have to be configured with a config file. But you can also use Gerrit (which is primarily a Code Review system, but you don't have to use the Review functionalities, and just use the access rights features). We use Gerrit in our company for that reason, and it has many features for access rights (groups, parent projects for common access rights for multiple projects etc.). Gerrit has a nice web interface to administer the projects (though you have to rely on SSH to create new projects).

Comment: You can also use one of the hosted Git providers, like Github, and setup private repositories with different collaborators.